# Does an SSL certificate targeted at users in China need to be generated by a Certificate Authority in China by law?

Tags: https, security-certificate

The company I work for is hosting a web page secured with login and password and working through SSL with a certificate generated in USA. This is already on production.

They want to expand the market to China and they have this idea that SSL certificate in this case needs to be generated by a Certificate Authority in China by law. Is this true?

Comment: It might be worth having a look at this question as well https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/100889/https-and-china

Comment: At least it is easy to find counterexamples, even if they may be edge cases. `amazon.cn` certificate CA is DigiCert... `www.apple.cn` is signed by some Apple subCA and then by GeoTrust.